# Xamarin iOS keyboard Covers Entry

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

My issue with the keyboard covering my Entry is very specific.  I have found two fixes to this issue.

1. Wrap the whole page in a scrollview, iOS by default will resize when the page is a scrollview. 
   This would work but the page is made for messaging and has a StackLayout with two children, a scrollview with all of the previous messages being displayed, and a Stacklayout with an entry field and an Image of an arrow.  When the StackLayout put into a scrollview the entry field stays at the bottom of the page which is not ideal.
   Here is an example of the first fix:
   https://www.screencast.com/t/mEf0VikS
2. I also found a render:
   https://github.com/adamped/SoftInput/blob/master/SoftInput/SoftInput.iOS/Render/KeyboardRender.cs this render would work but for reasons I do not know it would resize the page correctly, but will always send the user to the top of the page. Here is an example of the second fix:
   https://www.screencast.com/t/KzrZw92B20X

I would like to avoid using Nuget packages but if that is the only other way to fix this issue I would be ok with it.

Comment: Look at [here](https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/KeyboardOverlap)

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I'm using grid and stacks, wrap my root layout in a ScrollView and set the orientation to neither. And it works without any Nuget and code-behind.